# i want to do divide operation on @Html.DisplayFor

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

i want to do division operation on @Html.DisplayFor. how to do division on @Html.DisplayFor.

getting result like this 13004.7/1000 how to do 13.004 in the client side

```
<h1>@Html.DisplayFor(M => M.Volt)/1000</h1>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first calculate then assign the value, something like this

```
 @{
    decimal volt = Model.Volt / 1000;
  }
  <h1>@volt </h1>
```

**OR  easier way**

```
<h1>@(Model.Volt / 1000)</h1>
```